# How to take a maximum of several columns in R/dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data which looks basically like this:

```
id <- c(1:5)
VolumeA <- c(12, NA, NA, NA, NA)
VolumeB <- c(NA, 34, NA, NA, NA)
VolumeC <- c(NA, NA, 56, NA, NA)
VolumeD <- c(NA, NA, NA, 78, NA)
VolumeE <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 90)

df_now <- tibble(id, VolumeA, VolumeB, VolumeC, VolumeD, VolumeE)
df_now

# A tibble: 5 x 6
     id VolumeA VolumeB VolumeC VolumeD VolumeE
  <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1      12      NA      NA      NA      NA
2     2      NA      34      NA      NA      NA
3     3      NA      NA      56      NA      NA
4     4      NA      NA      NA      78      NA
5     5      NA      NA      NA      NA      90
```

In the IRL dataset, there are MANY more `Volume[label]` columns, but in each row I only need one of them: the largest one. So I want to create a new variable which has the largest value:

```
Volume <- c(12, 34, 56, 78, 90)
df_desired <- cbind(df_now, Volume)
df_desired

  id VolumeA VolumeB VolumeC VolumeD VolumeE Volume
1  1      12      NA      NA      NA      NA     12
2  2      NA      34      NA      NA      NA     34
3  3      NA      NA      56      NA      NA     56
4  4      NA      NA      NA      78      NA     78
5  5      NA      NA      NA      NA      90     90
```

After looking at the dplyr documentation, I tried this...

```
library(tidyverse)
df_try <- df_now %>%
  mutate(Volume = across(contains("Volume"), max, na.rm = TRUE))
```

...but got back a tibble of data, not a single column. Can someone tell me how to do this properly?

(Please assume, due to issues with my IRL data too complicated to explain here, that I cannot just `gather` and `spread` my data. I want to use a conditional `mutate`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `pmax` (first posted the `pmax` solution here).  Note that the relative improvement is very small with `do.call`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df_now %>%
    mutate(Volume = reduce(select(., starts_with('Volume')), pmax, na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 5 x 7
#     id VolumeA VolumeB VolumeC VolumeD VolumeE Volume
#  <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     1      12      NA      NA      NA      NA     12
#2     2      NA      34      NA      NA      NA     34
#3     3      NA      NA      56      NA      NA     56
#4     4      NA      NA      NA      78      NA     78
#5     5      NA      NA      NA      NA      90     90
```

---

Or with `c_across` and `max` (using only `tidyverse` approaches)

```
df_now %>%
   rowwise %>%
   mutate(Volume = max(c_across(starts_with('Volume')), na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 5 x 7
# Rowwise: 
#     id VolumeA VolumeB VolumeC VolumeD VolumeE Volume
#  <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     1      12      NA      NA      NA      NA     12
#2     2      NA      34      NA      NA      NA     34
#3     3      NA      NA      56      NA      NA     56
#4     4      NA      NA      NA      78      NA     78
#5     5      NA      NA      NA      NA      90     90
```

#### Benchmarks

```
system.time({df_now %>% mutate(Volume = reduce(select(., starts_with('Volume')), pmax, na.rm = TRUE))})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.023   0.006   0.029 

system.time({df_now %>% rowwise %>% mutate(Volume = max(c_across(starts_with('Volume')), na.rm = TRUE))})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.012   0.002   0.015 

system.time({df_now %>% mutate(Volume = do.call(pmax, c(select(., starts_with('Volume')), na.rm = TRUE)))})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.011   0.001   0.011
```

NOTE: Not that much difference in timings

Comment: Ideally, in your `c_across` variant, add `ungroup()` to prevent unexpected downstream side effects of `rowwise()`.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have *"MANY more `Volume[label]` columns"*, any solution that works over each row (`rowwise`) or individually on each column (with `reduce` or `Reduce`) is going to be much slower than necessary.

```r
df_now %>%
  mutate(Volume = do.call(pmax, c(select(., starts_with('Volume')), na.rm = TRUE)))
# # A tibble: 5 x 7
#      id VolumeA VolumeB VolumeC VolumeD VolumeE Volume
#   <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1     1      12      NA      NA      NA      NA     12
# 2     2      NA      34      NA      NA      NA     34
# 3     3      NA      NA      56      NA      NA     56
# 4     4      NA      NA      NA      78      NA     78
# 5     5      NA      NA      NA      NA      90     90
```

Proof of relative improvement:

1. Using `Reduce` or `purrr::reduce` or anything that will iterate per column (well, with `nc` columns, then it will iterate `nc-1` times):

   ```r
   mypmax <- function(...) { message("mypmax"); pmax(...); }
   df_now %>%
     mutate(Volume = reduce(select(., starts_with('Volume')), mypmax, na.rm = TRUE))
   # mypmax
   # mypmax
   # mypmax
   # mypmax
   # # A tibble: 5 x 7
   #      id VolumeA VolumeB VolumeC VolumeD VolumeE Volume
   #   <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
   # 1     1      12      NA      NA      NA      NA     12
   # 2     2      NA      34      NA      NA      NA     34
   # 3     3      NA      NA      56      NA      NA     56
   # 4     4      NA      NA      NA      78      NA     78
   # 5     5      NA      NA      NA      NA      90     90
   ```
2. Anything `rowwise` is doing this once per row, perhaps even worse (assuming more rows than columns in your data:

   ```r
   mymax <- function(...) { message("mymax"); max(...); }
   df_now %>%
     rowwise %>%
     mutate(Volume = mymax(c_across(starts_with('Volume')), na.rm = TRUE))
   # mymax
   # mymax
   # mymax
   # mymax
   # mymax
   # # A tibble: 5 x 7
   # # Rowwise: 
   #      id VolumeA VolumeB VolumeC VolumeD VolumeE Volume
   #   <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
   # 1     1      12      NA      NA      NA      NA     12
   # 2     2      NA      34      NA      NA      NA     34
   # 3     3      NA      NA      56      NA      NA     56
   # 4     4      NA      NA      NA      78      NA     78
   # 5     5      NA      NA      NA      NA      90     90
   ```
3. Do it *once* across all columns, all rows:

   ```r
   mypmax <- function(...) { message("mypmax"); pmax(...); }
   df_now %>%
     mutate(Volume = do.call(mypmax, c(select(., starts_with('Volume')), na.rm = TRUE)))
   # mypmax
   # # A tibble: 5 x 7
   #      id VolumeA VolumeB VolumeC VolumeD VolumeE Volume
   #   <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
   # 1     1      12      NA      NA      NA      NA     12
   # 2     2      NA      34      NA      NA      NA     34
   # 3     3      NA      NA      56      NA      NA     56
   # 4     4      NA      NA      NA      78      NA     78
   # 5     5      NA      NA      NA      NA      90     90
   ```

The benchmarking is minor at this scale, but will be more dramatic with larger data:

```r
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  red = df_now %>% mutate(Volume = reduce(select(., starts_with('Volume')), pmax, na.rm = TRUE)),
  row = df_now %>% rowwise %>% mutate(Volume = max(c_across(starts_with('Volume')), na.rm = TRUE)),
  sgl = df_now %>% mutate(Volume = do.call(pmax, c(select(., starts_with('Volume')), na.rm = TRUE)))
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
#   red 4.9736 5.36240 7.240561 5.68010 6.19915 70.7482   100
#   row 4.5813 5.02020 6.082047 5.34460 5.70345 63.1166   100
#   sgl 3.8270 4.18605 5.803043 4.43215 4.76030 65.7217   100
```

Comment: Akrun's `rowwise` solution is best for me, but I will keep the performance issues under consideration, thank you.

Comment: I don't have a problem with you taking his answer, he posted it first after all. Among all of them, `rowwise` is by far the worst for performance (not his implementation, just in general) when the number of rows increases significantly. Good luck.

Comment: FYI, if instead of 5 rows and 5 (non-`id`) columns you have 500 rows and 55 columns, then the median benchmark times are: red=21ms, row=40ms, sgl=5ms (on my machine). Times will of course vary. As long as you aren't dealing with more than a few hundred rows, you're probably fine. The `row=` execution scales with the number of rows, so 5000 rows is almost 100 times as long as sgl; 50000 rows almost 300 times as long.